# Can't change any text on my xcode project from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, text, storyboard

I Created an iOS App Before and now I wanted to change All the texts to another language.

I changed everything from Storyboard but when i run the app on Simulation, the previous version of app comes up and there is no change! Even when I changed the location of my project, still there were no changes !

Just PNG and JPG files changed.

My Xcode is 7.3.1
My OSX is 10.11.5

Comment: Do you mean your project is not localized properly ?

Comment: just follow this link: [Localization ](http://www.appcoda.com/localization-tutorial-ios8/)
may be doing some wrong in localization of application

Comment: No I don't want to localizate it, I just want to Simply change the app texts to another texts. but its not work ! it's so wierd ! it's so simple ! i can't blieve it ! It's ok on Storyboard but when i run it. all the old texts showing up !

Comment: do you mean another language or another font?

Comment: for example: i have a lable with this text: "hello" , i want to change it to : "bonjurno" . i change it with storyboard with no problem but when i run it, it show me "hello" !